# How to find the multiplicity of a proper factor with great efficiency?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, numbers, number-theory

I am trying to write a code to find out the given number with is a proper factor of n or not along with that I am also trying to find out the multiplicity of the given number.

Here is my code:

```
def f(n, d):
    '''
    >>> f(2, 1)
    1 is not a proper factor of 2.
    >>> f(2, 2)
    2 is not a proper factor of 2.
    >>> f(16, 2)
    2 is a proper factor of 16 of mutiplicity 4.
    >>> f(100, 20)
    20 is a proper factor of 100 of mutiplicity 1.
    >>> f(8 ** 7 * 3 ** 5 * 11 ** 2, 8)
    8 is a proper factor of 61662560256 of mutiplicity 7.
    >>> f(3 ** 3 * 11 * 13 ** 2 * 40 ** 6, 8)
    8 is a proper factor of 205590528000000 of mutiplicity 6.
    '''
    multiplicity = 0
    # Insert your code here
    if d == 1:
        print(f'{d} is not a proper factor of {n}.')
    if d == n:
        print(f'{d} is not a proper factor of {n}.')
    if n % d == 0:
        copy = n
        while(copy != 1):
            copy = copy // d
            multiplicity += 1
    if not multiplicity:
        print(f'{d} is not a proper factor of {n}.')
    else:
        print(f'{d} is a proper factor of {n} of mutiplicity {multiplicity}.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but f(12,4) should not be 2.  It's just a bug -- walk through what the program does for those inputs and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, I believe this loop has the wrong condition

```
while(copy != 1):
    copy = copy // d
    multiplicity += 1
```

What you want is to divide copy by d as long as copy is a multiple of d i.e.

```
while(copy % d == 0):
    copy = copy / d
    multiplicity += 1
```